# How can we alter the Linux file system hierarchy to something that's mine?

Tags: linux, filesystems, macos, lfs

I am building LFS & for some non-obvious reasons, I wanted to modify the file structure as MacOS has. For example:

- All libraries are in one directory
- All headers are in one directory
- All binaries are in one directory
  etc...

Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: What help do you need? What prevents you from copying and moving files?

Comment: Does simply copying/moving works? I mean when we `configure` our make file, doesn't it changes the code file. If yes, will it not result in any errors? For example, a program searching header files in `/include` will not find that because they are located somewhere else.

Comment: A program doesn't search for header files once it has been compiled. When you run the configure script to install or update software, use command line options to correct the paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As systems programmer preferences have changed over the decades, so too have the locations that various types of files get saved.  Those locations are usually hard-coded within programs and libraries.  You can't change that without rewriting many/most/all of the (potentially thousands) of programs and libraries that exist on your system.  If you simply move the files your OS will break.

If you prefer a file structure that is similar to MacOS, then you would be better off starting with something like Darwin, or you could pick one of the BSDs (which share the same lineage as MacOS).

It would be a **substantial** and *ongoing* effort to shoehorn a 'typical Linux distribution' into a MacOS/BSD-like filesystem.  You'd have to download all of the sources, rewrite large amounts of them, compile and link them, and do exactly the same thing each and every time you wanted to update anything.

If you are building a very, very small custom Linux system, with a very, very limited number of functions (preferably one) then it *might* be worth spending a few weeks/months doing the required conversion.  If you want a general-purpose system, however, then forget about it.  I doubt anyone on the planet has the amount of spare time required to even attempt such a task.

Or... have a look at **GoboLinux** ( https://www.gobolinux.org/ ) which have already tackled the "files scattered all over the place" problem.  Maybe their approach would be 'good enough' for you?

Comment: Okay Tim, but let say I have the source of the program. One way to do this is to `find & replace` each occurrence of a directory. For eg: `/include`will be replaced by `/Library`. Is there any problem in that?

Comment: Plain text search & replace does not work on Binary Blobs, so if you are using a Nvidia dGPU and want to actually play anything at a decent frame rate, then that is a brick wall grep simply can not get you over.  Ditto for other device drivers such as Bluetooth, Wi-Fi, printers and so-on.  Yes, it is possible to easily convert some pieces of software.  Others can be made to work by simply altering compile-time flags.  Some can be changed with environment variables.  Some, however, can't be changed — at all (unless you feel like reverse-engineering a binary blob).

Comment: If you absolutely want a Linux-based system, then possibly(?) your best bet would be to only include POSIX-compliant software.  Whether it is possible to actually build a fully-POSIX-compliant Linux system in 2021 that would actually work on your hardware, and deliver the features you want, is another matter entirely.

Comment: Does simply copying/moving works? I mean when we `configure` our make file, doesn't it changes the code file. If yes, will it not result in any errors? For example, a program searching header files in `/include` will not find that because they are located somewhere else.

Comment: As I wrote earlier, there are multiple approaches to solving the problem.  Each approach works with some software, but not others.  There is no 'one approach' that works with all of the software that can be found on a typical, general-purpose system.  Exceptions and edge-cases are everywhere.  Did you check out GoboLinux, by the way?

Comment: It's installing. What's special you want me to see there. Can you give a spoiler please!

Comment: The considerations in this answer are valid for typical distros that provide software in binary form via package managers. Package managers make certain assumptions where files are located, and I guess it would be very hard to make them change those assumptions. However, OP uses **LFS**. There is no package manager. Where the source, libraries, header files and binaries are located is entirely in OP's control. All OP has to do is provide the correct paths when installing or updating software. The `configure` scripts that come with source code usually allow this.

Comment: @Hunny Gobo uses a variety of strategies to make the location of files "make more sense".  https://www.gobolinux.org/at_a_glance.html  You seem to want the location of files to make more sense also.  Although they use a different approach compared to Apple, their approach may "make sense" to your brain, in which case you might be satisfied with that.  Nothing more than that.  Gobo wasn't around the last time I played with LFS.

Comment: @berndbausch Yes, but if the OP wants to do something 'simple' like watch a YouTube or Netflix video, then the required code base simply isn't open source, so that isn't possible.  The last time I tried, you couldn't build a LFS system that could do that sort of thing without relying on closed-source binaries with immutable hard-coded file paths.  If that has changed then I'd love to know.  I also have BT peripherals that need closed-source drivers and pose the same problem.  If the OP wants to simply build something like a headless DNS or mail server, then I think it's doable.

Comment: Okay, so do linux kernel enforce any kind of file structure. Eg: "You have to create /etc/inittab" or similar?

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/index.html would probably be the authoritative source to consult for that type of question.  A more gentle introduction: https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/linux-filesystem-explained/

Comment: The kernel doesn't care. The Linux kernel is used in very diverse devices, telephones, PCs, embedded devices, mainframes, which have different file structures.